# Solr WordDelimiterFilterFactory and Period Characters

Tags: solr, lucene, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I am using solr through the sunspot_rails v1.2 gem.

In my schema.xml file, I have the following:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" catenateWords="1" preserveOriginal="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="50" side="front"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" preserveOriginal="1"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

If I index the string `firstname.lastname@example.com`, I can find it if I search for `example.com`, but not if I search for `firstname.lastname`.

If I remove `WordDelimiterFilterFactory` from the query settings, then I can the email by searching for `firstname.lastname`; however, nothing comes up when I search for `example.com`.

How can I modify the configuration file to be able to search by either of these means?

Comment: Note: I found out what the main issue is.  Apparently, the order in which filters are listed matters.  I was applying the WordDelimiterFilterFactory *after* the LowerCaseFilterFactory, and was thus indexing some capitalized words.

Answer (score 1):

You could debug how your current index & query analysis configuration are affecting your searches, by using [Solr Admin Analysis Page](http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/analysis.jsp), another option is to use [Luke](http://code.google.com/p/luke/) to peek into Lucene index.

However, there is an alternative that you could explore. Since, Email & URL needs to be handled in a specific way, Lucene has variant of StandardTokenizer that specifically deals with Email & URL [Lucene Email/URL Tokenizer](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_5_0/api/all/index.html?org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/UAX29URLEmailTokenizer.html) corresponding [Solr Email/URL Tokenizer Factory](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/index.html?org/apache/solr/analysis/UAX29URLEmailTokenizerFactory.html)